# Tutorial wants me to "Download signalr.js file from a CDN"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm attempting to set up a push notificaton functionality for my asp.net core system.

I'm looking at using Signalr for it, and I found [this one](https://www.zealousweb.com/signalr-to-send-real-time-notifications-with-asp-net-core/?fbclid=IwAR1hSmT_LA6EyFvHD245J7AlHYPQQM4tSI7Z94_dLi7TtgD0RZKBC0z5nOM).

It's fairly intuitive, except for the sixth step, where I need a `signal.js` file:

```
Step 6: Download signalr.js file from a CDN & place it inside wwwroot -> lib -> signalr folder.
```

I have no idea what this means. Why would a cloud delivery network have a signalR client file for me?

Does anyone know what this means? and more importantly where I should look?

Answer (score 1):

In [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-the-signalr-client-library), you can find:

*`The SignalR server library is included in the ASP.NET Core 3.1 shared framework. The JavaScript client library isn't automatically included in the project.`*

So to setup a SignalR JavaScript client app, you need to add/install the SignalR client library in your project first.

And referencing a CDN-hosted copy of the client library is also a way to include SignalR client library. For more information about how to install the SignalR client package in different ways, you can check following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#install-the-signalr-client-package